# How to replace contents of parent element, ignoring children using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some HTML like this:

```
<div id="demo">
    <p>
        <span class="myClass">Word test should not be marked</span>
        Word test should be marked<br />
    </p>
</div>
```

How can I find a word ('test') inside the `div` excluding the `span` and mark it using jQuery? I have seen a lot of solutions in SO, etc. but none of them worked for me. FYI the code I'm trying to use is something like this :

```
var regex = XRegExp('test', 'i');
$('#demo').markRegExp(regex);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. Do you want just highlight the word `test` by wrap it with `span` inside the `.myClass` span?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get  all child nodes using **[`contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)** and then iterate and update the text nodes.

```js
$('#demo p')
  .contents() // get all child nodes including text and comment nodes
  .each(function() { // iterate over nodes
    if (this.nodeType == 3) // check node is text node
      $(this).replaceWith(this.textContent.replace(/test/g, '<span class="test">$&</span>')) // update the content and replace node with html content
  });
```

```css
.test {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <p>
    <span class="myClass">Word test should not be marked</span>
    Word test should be marked
    <br />
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please check the fix I just added to your code is what you intended, I think it  is, otherwise it fails

Comment: Doesn't work. `Word test should be marked` still is in root of `p`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddly regex solution:

```
    var html=$("#demo").html();
    var elements=html.split(/(<[^>]+>)/); // split into tags and text
    $.each(elements,function(i,e){
    if(!e.match(/<[^>]+>/)){
        if(elements[i-1]!==undefined){
        if(!$(elements[i-1]).hasClass('myClass')){
            elements[i]=elements[i].replace(/test/g,"<span class='highlight'>test</span>");
        }
      }
    }
  });
  $("#demo").html(elements.join(''));
```

It would be much cleaner, though, to mark the text you *do* want to replace with a class, then you could just do:

```
$("#demo").find("span[class='myClass']").each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/test/g,"<span class='highlight'>test</span>"));
});
```

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/praine/39wvLLa9/77/) for both solutions.